# Curl Wrapper Class does not return any data even though it worked previously?

Tags: php, curl, filestream

We changed servers and installed all necessary software and just cannot seem to pin point what is going on. A simple CURL request does not return anything. Command Line CURL commands work just fine. We are using a wrapper for CURL utilizing streams. Do PHP streams require any out of the ordinary configuration? We are using the latest Lamp stack.

This is the var_dump:

The var_dump can be seen at:

http://jinimetrix.com/test.php

Comment: You would be more apt to get a response if you reduced how much of the var_dump you put in the question, and added more of the code you used to get it.

Comment: wow, now that is some useless chunck, why not link to a formated easier to read hosted file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you used `phpinfo();` to verify that cURL is in fact detected?

Just create a test page containing only:

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

and verify that the section entitled "curl" appears.